# node.js promise-sequene run a function between each task

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using `promise-sequence/lib/pipeline`, and I have a basic pipeline:

```
  var resultsPromise = pipeline([
    commonFunctions.accessURL(nightmare),
    commonFunctions.loginToWebsite(nightmare),
  ])
  .then(() => commonFunctions.success(nightmare))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

`.then()` will run at the end, `.catch()` will run in case of an error.

What I need is to run a function called: commonFunctions.recordLog() before starting each function in pipeline or after each function in pipeline.

How can I achieve this?

## EDIT

To make sure that you understand what I want to achieve, here is one example:

```
var resultsPromise = pipeline([
commonFunctions.accessURL(nightmare),
commonFunctions.recordLog()
commonFunctions.loginToWebsite(nightmare),
commonFunctions.recordLog()
commonFunctions.loginToWebsite(nightmare),
commonFunctions.recordLog()
commonFunctions.loginToWebsite(nightmare),
commonFunctions.recordLog()
])
.then(() => commonFunctions.success(nightmare))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

This would work, but it's not the best solution.

Comment: Is your commonFunctions.recordLog() function async so we should wait after each step? Does it return a promise if so?

Comment: Yes, it is async.

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline passes the result of a previous task to the next task as a parameter.

So not to break the calculations we need to wrap commonFunctions.recordLog() call into a function that takes an argument, then calls recordLog and returns it's argument without any modifications.

If the commonFunctions.recordLog() is async and returns a promise the wrapper will look like this:

```
x => commonFunctions.recordLog().then(() => x)
```

As you can see it resolves with 'x' disregarding of what recordLog returns.

If the commonFunctions is sync you can simply do:

```
x => {
    commonFunctions.recordLog();
    return x;
}
```

Also I'd write a function to insert this additional tasks automatically like this:

```js
let addLogTasks = function (tasks) {
 let tasksWithLogging = [];

 for (let task of tasks) {
  tasksWithLogging.push(task, x => commonFunctions.recordLog().then(() => x));
 }

 return tasksWithLogging;
};

//And then
pipeline(addLogTasks(pipelineTasks))
 .then((x) => console.log(x))
 .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: There is an error here `for (let task of tasks) {` says it's not a function.

Comment: What about IF i need the data of the previous task?

Comment: @PHPLover let's figure it out. What is the error that it throws? 'then' is not a function? Also did I get it right that you want to use data from prev. task inside recordLog? Then you can pass 'x' to it.